# Only some FontAwesome 5 icons not showing up, only sometimes

Tags: sass, font-awesome, compass-sass, font-awesome-5

We recently successfully upgraded to Font Awesome 5, or so we thought.

The strange problem we're having is that some FA5 icons don't show up, *but only sometimes*. That is, on some pages the icon is there, but on others it's not.

Everything worked A OK locally and on our testing server. It's just on our production server that we see this.

We set all icons the same way, with a mixin:

```
@mixin icon(
  $name
) {
  $font-icon: map-get($font-icons, $name);

  @if $font-icon {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

    content: fa-unicode($font-icon);
    font-weight: fa-weight($font-icon);
  } else {
    // use an image, deleted to keep it short
  }
```

where `$font-icons` maps between a name and a tuple of the FontAwesome unicode and `font-weight`:

```
$font-icons: (
  filter: ($fa-var-filter, 900),
  // etc etc
```

`$fa-var-filter` is defined in Font Awesome's `_variables.scss` as `$fa-var-filter: \f0b0;`.

for completeness, here are the two helper functions:

```
@function fa-unicode($font) {
  @return unquote("\"#{ nth($font, 1) }\"");
}

@function fa-weight($font) {
  @return nth($font, 2)
}
```

In thinking about how this mechanism can have such different results *on the same page*, I'm leaning towards something breaking compass's or sass's compilation. But really haven't the foggiest.

Comment: What’s the difference in the compilation between  the so called local and production? Production is a minified version? Which compiler are you using? Do you compile local and then deploy to server or the files are compiled server side?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Chrome...I have a font awesome 5 layer that shows a file icon and then an overlayed paperclip icon when the file is attached. The html looks exactly the same on the ones that show and the ones that don't, but I cannot figure out why this is happening